# How to set default permissions for all applications to a windows 7 image?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, iso-image

I will be using the Extended Change Access Control List tool (Xcacls.exe) application to perform this task and after looking at the tool I can apply changes to files and folders easily.

My goal is for any application installed in windows 7 on any user to have the modify permission by default. I understand that I can use xcacls command on files and folders and I thought about using the command on the program files directory and that would work on most applications but for other cases when an application is stored in the c drive itself, how would I deal whith these application?

Could I add the modify (change in xcacls) to all folders in the C drive except the folders I know will be there from the beggining and are sensitive like Windows directory? Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Files can be modified by standard users by default. This looks like a noop.

Comment: when you say files, would that be all files including files the windows directory? The Windows os I am working with just has read for default users and modify toggled off. I am also trying to make this chage to the iso itself and modify ntfs permissions.

Comment: Files in the Windows directory inherit their permissions from the Windows directory. You are not proposing changing the permissions of files there are you?

Comment: No definitely not in the windows directory. To add more clarifiction I am working with ghost images and I want to make an image where only applications have the modify permission for all users, but I'm working with an image that does not allow modify for standard users and the modify permision must be enabled for all folders in admin mode.

Comment: I think with each comment my understanding of what you are asking decreases. I'll step aside and hope that somebody else is better equipped to help. Sorry.

Comment: The question is kind of confused because applications are not security principals. Applications cannot have permissions. *Users* have permissions.

Comment: I like with question but from other view. When I move external HDD from one host to another **SIDs** become invalid and as default permission to all does not grant I can not read files/dirs. If it is possible set default permission for newly created/copied file I resolve my issue: http://superuser.com/questions/353739/have-issue-with-access-denied-invalid-descriptor-and-external-storage-for-w